# ¿Cómo puedo abrir una nueva ventana pasando parámetros por POST?

Tags: javascript, jquery

¿Cómo puedo redireccionar a través de *jQuery* a una nueva página, pasándole parámetros por post?

Tengo el siguiente código:

Código *PHP*:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>llegamos</title>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body >
    <h1 id="cabecera"><p>Resultado</p></h1>
        <?php
            $cantidadCheckBox = htmlspecialchars($_POST['cantCheck']);
            $arrChk = array();
            for ($i=0; $i < $cantidadCheckBox; $i++) { 
                $nuevoChk = htmlspecialchars($_POST['chk'.$i]);
                if ($nuevoChk != "") {
                    array_push($arrChk, explode(",", $nuevoChk));
                }
            }
        ?>

        <div id="cuerpo">
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/html2canvas/0.4.1/html2canvas.min.js"></script>
        <?php
            foreach ($arrChk as $key) {
                        echo '<img src="formulario.jpg" style="width: 100%;">';
                        //echo "<tr style='hiden: true'><td>".$key[0]."</td><td>".$key[1]."</td><td>".$key[2]."</td></tr>";
                        echo '<input type="text" value="'.$key[0].'" style="width: 7%; heigth: 2%; position: absolute;margin-top: 4.1%;margin-left: -91%; z-index:10 ;border-width: 0px;">';
                        echo '<input type="text" value="'.$key[1].'" style="width: 7%; heigth: 2%; position: absolute;margin-top: 4.1%;margin-left: -48.5%; z-index:10 ;border-width: 0px;">';
                        echo '<input type="text" value="'.$key[2].'" style="width: 7%; heigth: 2%; position: absolute;margin-top: 6.7%;margin-left: -64%; z-index:10 ;border-width: 0px;">';
                        //echo '</div>';
                    }
        ?>
        <!--
        <input type="text" value="" style="position: absolute;margin-top: -200px;margin-left: 100px; border-width: 0px;">
            <table  border="1" style="width: 100%; color: red;">
                <thead>
                    <th>Nombre</th>
                    <th>Asignación</th>
                    <th>Fecha</th>
                </thead>
                <?php
                    foreach ($arrChk as $key) {
                        echo "<tr><td>".$key[0]."</td><td>".$key[1]."</td><td>".$key[2]."</td></tr>";
                    }
                ?>
            </table>-->
        </div>

        <button onclick="exportar()">Exportar</button>
         <a id="download">Tomar screenshot y descargar</a>
<div id="visualizacion"></div>
<p id="pie">esto es el pie</p>
    </body>
</html>
```

Código *jQuery*:

```
function exportar() {
    html2canvas($("#cuerpo"), {
        onrendered (canvas) {
            var link = document.getElementById('download');;
            //var image = canvas.toDataURL();
            //link.href = image;
            //link.download = 'screenshot.png';
            $("#visualizacion").html('<img src="'+canvas.toDataURL()+'" onload="listo()">');
        }
    });
}
function listo(){
    cabecera = $("#cabecera").html();
    pie = $("#pie").html();
    cuerpo = $("#visualizacion").html();
    //window.location.href = 'imprimir.php?cabecera='+cabecera+'&pie='+pie+'&cuerpo='+cuerpo;                   
}
```

En la variable `cuerpo` se deja alojada una captura de pantalla, pero cuando intenté enviarle estos datos por *GET*, me indicó que el largo del dato era demasiado para la *URL*. Por tanto necesito hacer como un **submit desde *jQuery***, donde pueda cargar la nueva página, pero enviando estos datos por *POST*.

Comment: intentastes llenar un formulario tipo hidden y hacerle post al formulario?

Comment: para abrir una nueva ventana debes usar `window.open`... de no ser lo que quieres mejora la pregunta ;))...

Comment: Pregunte por redireccionar y pasarlo por post. Algo como el típico <form>, pero sin ocuparlo en el html, sino en jquery

Answer (score 0):

Debe crear un formulario de manera dinamica y enviarlo por **POST** asi puedes enviar multiples variables con la longitud que quieras, esta es una solucion:

```
function listo(){
        cabecera = $("#cabecera").html();
        pie = $("#pie").html();
        cuerpo = $("#visualizacion").html();
        var form = $("<form/>", 
                         { action:'imprimir.php' , 
                         method : 'POST'}
                    );
        form.append( 
            $("<input>", 
                 { type :'text', 
                    id  :  'cabecera',
                   name :'cabecera', 
                   value: cabecera }
             )
        );
        form.append( 
            $("<input>", 
                 { type  :'text', 
                    id   :  'pie',
                   name  :'pie', 
                   value : pie }
             )
        );
        form.append( 
            $("<input>", 
                 { type  :'text', 
                    id   :  'cuerpo',
                   name  :'cuerpo', 
                   value : cuerpo }
             )
        );
        //quitar luego solo modo practico
        form.append( 
             $("<input>", 
                  { type:'submit', 
                    value:'Search' }
               )
        );

        $("#idformulario").append(form);
        form.submit();

    }
```

en el html

```
<div id="idformulario">

</div>
```

Si quieres que no se vea en el html cambia los campos a tipo hidden, pero para ejemplo practico recomiendo dejarlo hasta que depueres la aplicacion la solucion tambien en https://jsfiddle.net/99tn36tv/2/

Comment: JackNavaRow, ¿podrías elaborar un poco más tu respuesta para aclarar como funciona la solución que propones? La respuesta se reporto automáticamente como baja calidad y podría ser cerrada ya que el código no contiene explicaciones. Mira esta guía [__Cómo responder__](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).